# threejs getImageData video performance

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, html5-video, getimagedata

**Edit;**

working codepen (need to provide video file to avoid cross-origin policy)

https://codepen.io/bw1984/pen/pezOXm

---

I am attempting to modify the excellent rutt etra example here https://airtightinteractive.com/demos/js/ruttetra/ to work for video (still using threejs) and am encountering strange issues with performance.

My code currently works as expected, and actually runs quite smoothly on chrome on my macbook pro, but seems to cause some sort of slow memory leak which i assume is to do with all the heavy lifting which is having to be done by getImageData. Strangely enough its only noticeable once i attempt to refresh the tab, so looks like it may be related to the garbage collection in chrome maybe? anyway to shunt the grunt work onto the GPU instead of killing the CPU?

I just wondered if i am missing anything obvious in terms of code optimisation or if the performance issues i am facing are to be expected given the nature of what i am trying to do.

I am only interested in WebGL / chrome functionality so dont really need to worry about browser compatibility of any kind.

```
<script>

var container, camera, scene, renderer, controls;

// PI
var PI = Math.PI;
var TWO_PI = PI*2;

// size

SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;
SCREEN_PIXEL_RATIO = window.devicePixelRatio;

// camera

var VIEW_ANGLE = 45;
var ASPECT = SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT;
var NEAR = 0.1;
var FAR = 20000000;



// video raster

var video;
var videoImage;
var videoImageContext;

var _imageHeight;
var _imageWidth;


// lines

var _lineGroup;


// gui

var _guiOptions = {
    stageSize:      1,
    scale:          1.0,
    scanStep:       5,
    lineThickness:  10.0,
    opacity:        1.0,
    depth:          50,
    autoRotate:     false
};


// triggered from audio.php getMediaStream

function runme()
{
    console.log('runme running');

    init();
    animate();
}

runme();


function init() 
{
    container = document.createElement('div');
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    //----------
    // scene
    //----------

        scene = new THREE.Scene();


    //----------
    // camera
    //----------

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);

        //camera.position.set(0,0,450);

        camera.position.set(0,150,300);


    //----------
    // objects
    //----------

        // create the video element
        video = document.createElement('video');
        // video.id = 'video';
        // video.type = ' video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis" ';
        video.src = 'data/sintel.ogv';
        //video.src = 'data/az.mp4';

        video.load(); // must call after setting/changing source
        video.play();

        videoImage = document.createElement('canvas');
        //videoImage.width = 480;
        //videoImage.height = 204;

        videoImageContext = videoImage.getContext('2d');

        _imageWidth = videoImage.width;
        _imageHeight = videoImage.height;

        //videoImageContext.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
        //videoImageContext.fillRect(0, 0, videoImage.width, videoImage.height);



    //----------
    // controls
    //----------

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);


    //----------
    // events
    //----------

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);


    //----------
    // render
    //----------

        var args = {
            //antialias: true // too slow
        }

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(args);

        renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(SCREEN_PIXEL_RATIO); //Set pixel aspect ratio
        renderer.setSize(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

        // attach to dom
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

        //render();
}


function render()
{

    if(video.readyState === video.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA && !video.paused && !video.ended) // and video.currentTime > 0 
    {
        //_imageWidth = videoImage.width;
        //_imageHeight = videoImage.height;

        videoImageContext.drawImage(video,0,0,_imageWidth,_imageHeight);


        // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
        var _data = videoImageContext.getImageData(0,0,videoImage.width,videoImage.height).data;

        //log(data);

        //_pixels = data;

        var x = 0, y = 0;

        if(_lineGroup)
        {
            scene.remove(_lineGroup);
            //_lineGroup = null;
        }

        _lineGroup = new THREE.Object3D();


        var _material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
            color: 0xffffff,
            linewidth: _guiOptions.lineThickness
        });


        // loop through the image pixels

        for(y = 0; y < _imageHeight; y+= _guiOptions.scanStep) 
        {

            var _geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            for(x=0; x<_imageWidth; x+=_guiOptions.scanStep) 
            {
                var color = new THREE.Color(getColor(x, y, _data));

                var brightness = getBrightness(color);

                var posn = new THREE.Vector3(x -_imageWidth/2,y - _imageHeight/2, -brightness * _guiOptions.depth + _guiOptions.depth/2);

                //_geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vertex(posn));
                _geometry.vertices.push(posn);

                _geometry.colors.push(color);

                _color = null;
                _brightness = null;
                _posn = null;
            }

            // add a line
            var _line = new THREE.Line(_geometry, _material);

            //log(line);

            _lineGroup.add(_line);

            // gc
            _geometry = null;
        }

        scene.add(_lineGroup);

        _data = null;
        _line = null;

    }

    renderer.render(scene,camera);
}


function animate(){

    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    stats.update();

    render();
}


function onWindowResize(){

    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    render();
}



// Returns a hexadecimal color for a given pixel in the pixel array.

function getColor(x, y, _pixels)
{
    var base = (Math.floor(y) * _imageWidth + Math.floor(x)) * 4;

    var c = {
        r: _pixels[base + 0],
        g: _pixels[base + 1],
        b: _pixels[base + 2],
        a: _pixels[base + 3]
    };
    return (c.r << 16) + (c.g << 8) + c.b;
}



// return pixel brightness between 0 and 1 based on human perceptual bias

function getBrightness(c) 
{
    return ( 0.34 * c.r + 0.5 * c.g + 0.16 * c.b );
}

</script>
```

any help anyone could provide would be much appreciated, even if its just pointing me in the right direction as i am only just beginning to experiment with this stuff and have almost given myself an aneurysm trying to wrap my tiny mind around it.

Comment: also worth reiterating... please be aware that the code as it currently stands may cause chrome to crash

Comment: I've been reading through it not fully understanding what it's supposed to do, but as soon as i reached a `new THREE.Line` i thought theres the culprit. Whatever you are doing here, you should cache, you should either have a geometry constructed ( lines in a rectangle ) or have a pool of lines that you can position each frame. In the render loop, i believe this stresses the memory since each one of those nodes has a bunch of data and that data is often in forms of objects too (vectors and matrices mostly).

Comment: overall, you don't need to read the video and do this on the cpu, just read it as a texture and do it in the shader

Comment: thanks for your suggestions @pailhead, you have definitely given me a nudge in the right direction in terms of trying to instantiate THREE.Line more sparingly so I will try that first. I've got no idea what you mean about reading the video as a texture though, and have a really limited understanding of shaders. can you elaborate on that at all? any suggested reading? I will reply to your answer separately once I've had a chance to do some tests

Comment: Well, you read the data on the cpu and then do your computation, which is slow. Starting from the reading part i believe, so you could avoid it by just keeping it on the gpu. This would unfortunately require that the rest of the logic also happens in the shaders.

http://learningwebgl.com/blog/ is a decent resource. This one is for opengl but explains some concepts really well: http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-1-opening-a-window/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The slow memory leak is most likely due to:

```
        // add a line
        var _line = new THREE.Line(_geometry, _material);

        //log(line);

        _lineGroup.add(_line);
```

`THREE.Line` is an object, containing other objects and lots of data. Every time you instantiate it, it creates `.matrix`, `.matrixWorld`, `.modelViewMatrix`, `.normalMatrix` which are all arrays with a bunch of numbers. `.position`,`.quaternion`, `.scale`, `.rotation` and probably `.up` are vectors,quats etc. and are slightly smaller but also arrays with special constructors.

Allocating all this every 16 miliseconds only to be released the next frame is probably the cause of your "leak".

You should create a pool of `THREE.Line` objects, and draw that every frame instead. The number of drawn objects you can control with `.visible` and mutate their transformation properties.

Answer (score 0):

@pailhead I took your advice about pre-rendering the lines and lineGroup in advance and then updating the vertices on each animation frame instead and now its purring like a kitten. Also needed to insert the following line to make sure updated coords are picked up;

```
e.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

I cant figure out how to get a hosted video to work on codepen (cross-origin policy violation issues) but i have put a version up anyway to show the working code.

https://codepen.io/bw1984/pen/pezOXm

I will try to get a self-hosted (working) version up as soon as i can

I've been trying in vain to get colour working, but that will have to be an exercise for another day.